# Missing Import button in the modules of Odoo 13 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, module, odoo, import-from-excel, time-and-attendance

In Odoo 13 version, I saw the Export all button in the modules (Attendances, Employees...), but the Import button still invisible, after changing to the List View mode. What's wrong?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Odoo version 13 import option is removed from the attendance. Let's wait for the update from Odoo.

Comment: Hi Pablo, Thank you for your answer. I'm clearly understand!